# How to include external jar within package

Tags: spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

I have spring boot project which is packaged into jar.
I have external jar(Jasper) add into pom like below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jasperreports-6.13.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-jasperreports613</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/lib/jasperreports-6.13.0.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                            <version>6.13.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When run jar (java -jar myapp.jar) i am gettig classdefNotfound for jasper.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[e-statement-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

When i extracted the package and there is no jasper lib is included in package.
How to include the external libraries into package.

Comment: The reason I have added it as external is that the access is restrcited in network level.

Comment: So you are inside a company network? Does your company have a Nexus or Artifactory server?

Comment: Yes correct . We do have have nexus repository but for current project  not supposed to use bcs should run as stand alone jar in Linux server . So I was trying to find if there is a way apart from using repository and include external lib within the application package.

Comment: The way to do this is as follows: You build your project with the help Nexus (this will hopefully also serve you jasperreports). To build an executable jar, you use the Maven shade plugin or the Maven assembly plugin in your POM. The resulting jar will then include the dependencies, also those from Nexus. You don't need any systemPath or install-file for that.

Answer (score 1):

The jar `jasperreports` is on MavenCentral. So if you have internet access, there is no need to handle that manually.